# What's most optimized way to load multiple pdfs in a react/nextjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I need to load 10 pdfs scrollable on the same page

Each PDF file contains multiple pages and weighs between 10 and 30MB each.

I'm trying to avoid loading over 200MB of data on the front end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm mostly asking what the best way to load pdf on the front end without overloading the user

Comment: @nt5556 What specifically would make one method "better" than another? Do you have any candidate methods that we can compare?